how to set chinese lanaguage support in github actions
I use vs2022 build c++ project
I use printf and write Chinese string.
I found that Chinese characters are all gibberish.like this:


my build script
name: C++ Build with Dependencies

#on: [push] 
on:
  workflow_dispatch: 
  
permissions:
  contents: write
  
jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        configuration: [Release]
        platform: [x86]

    runs-on: windows-latest 

    steps:
      - name: Checkout main repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Console Code Page to GBK
        run: chcp 936
        shell: pwsh
        
      - name: Checkout dependency repository (xengine)
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: libxengine/xengine
          path: xengine

      - name: Set up Dependency Environment Variables
        run: |
          echo "XENGINE_INCLUDE=${{ github.workspace }}/xengine" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_ENV -Append
          echo "XENGINE_LIB32=${{ github.workspace }}/xengine/XEngine_Windows/x86" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_ENV -Append
          echo "XENGINE_LIB64=${{ github.workspace }}/xengine/XEngine_Windows/x64" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_ENV -Append
        shell: pwsh
        
      - name: Setup MSBuild
        uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2
      #编译
      - name: Build Solution
        run: msbuild XEngine_Source/XEngine_StorageApp.sln /p:Configuration=${{ matrix.configuration }} /p:Platform=${{ matrix.platform }}

      - name: Copy Build binaries for x86
        run: |
          mkdir -p "x86/XEngine_StorageApp"
          cp -r ./XEngine_Release/* x86/XEngine_StorageApp/
          cp -r ./XEngine_Source/Release/*.dll x86/XEngine_StorageApp/
          cp -r ./XEngine_Source/Release/*.exe x86/XEngine_StorageApp/
          cp -r ./XEngine_Source/VSCopy_x86.bat x86/XEngine_StorageApp/
          cd x86/XEngine_StorageApp && ./VSCopy_x86.bat
          cd ..
          cd ..
          7z a XEngine_StorageApp-x86-Windows.zip ./x86/XEngine_StorageApp
        shell: pwsh

      - name: Calculate new tag
        id: newtag
        shell: bash
        run: |
          git fetch --tags
          TAG=$(git tag --sort=-v:refname | head -n 1)
          MAJOR=$(echo $TAG | cut -d '.' -f 1)
          MINOR=$(echo $TAG | cut -d '.' -f 2)
          PATCH=$(echo $TAG | cut -d '.' -f 3)
          BUILD=$(echo $TAG | cut -d '.' -f 4)
          MINOR_BUMP=$((MINOR + 1))
          NEW_TAG="${MAJOR}.${MINOR_BUMP}.0.${BUILD}"
          echo "NEW_TAG=$NEW_TAG" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
          git tag $NEW_TAG
          git push origin $NEW_TAG
    
      - name: Create Release
        id: create_release
        uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ env.NEW_TAG }}
          name: Release ${{ env.NEW_TAG }}
          body: |
            [${{ github.sha }}](https://github.com/xengine-qyt/XEngine_Storage/commit/${{ github.sha }})
            ${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}
          draft: false
          prerelease: false
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
     
      - name: Upload x86 Release Asset
        uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}
          asset_path: ./XEngine_StorageApp-x86-Windows.zip
          asset_name: XEngine_StorageApp-x86-Windows.zip
          asset_content_type: application/zip

In my own Chinese system environment, the output is normal. When I try to code to output the UNICODE string, it doesn't work. What should I do to output Chinese?

Don't post images in your questions. Check out how to ask.

Switch everything to UTF-8.

@AndréLehto, while I agree in general that images of text are bad, I'd consider this an exception to the rule.

I haven't used anything beyond ASCII for this, so I can't give you a solution, only a few things I would look at. For a start, check out whether GitHub supports those Chinese characters at all, by changing the name:  in that file to some Chinese text. If that isn't rendered correctly in the GUI, I'm afraid you're out of luck. Then, find out whether output from Powershell works. I think that chcp 936 may not work properly. For one, it's executed in one shell and the output happens in another shell. The other thing is that for UTF-8, you need a different codepage.

my all code are utf8-bom....

The steps will run in independent shell environment. The chcp 936 won't affect the subsequent steps. You need add it to the specific step which uses the GBK characters.

how to set.test not work.   - name: Build Solution
run: |
chcp 936
msbuild ....
shell: pwsh
